# VM jump when accessing statically set variables

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, contract-debugging, bad-jump, integers

Hey it seems I get a jump error when I try to access any variable not set through a parameter in the constructor. amountRaised is throwing a jump error below as I try to statically set the value.

```
 contract Project {
 address public fundingHub; 
 address public projectCreator; 
 string public title; 
 string public description;
 uint256 public amountToBeRaised; 
 uint256 public deadline;
 uint256 public amountRaised; 

function Project(address _creator, uint256 _amountToBeRaised, uint256 _deadline, string _title, string _description) {
    if (_amountToBeRaised <= 0) { throw; }
    if (_deadline <= block.timestamp) { throw; }
    fundingHub = msg.sender;  
    projectCreator = _creator;
    title = _title; 
    description = _description; 
    amountToBeRaised = _amountToBeRaised;
    amountRaised = 0; 
    deadline = _deadline; 
}
}
```

The javascript looks like this

```
            return thisProject.deadline.call(); 
      }).then(function(_deadline) { 
          console.log("this is the deadline" + _deadline.valueOf());
          return thisProject.amountRaised.call(); 
        }).then(function(_amountRaised) { 
          console.log(_amountRaised.valueOf()); 
          return thisProject.amountToBeRaised.call(); 
        }).then(function(_amountToBeRaised) { 
          console.log(_amountToBeRaised.valueOf());
        });
  }
```

Comment: Something fishy about the code posted. fundingHub is undefined at fundingHub = msg.sender.

Comment: Ya sorry I didn't include funding hub...I'll fix it now.

Comment: It's clear the value is gettable in Browser Solidity. One possibility is your thisProject is out of sync with the deployed contract and the getter function isn't in the deployed compiled code your JS is talking to, in which case the default fallback function will throw. It looks like truffle, so possibly $ truffle migrate --reset and $ truffle build just to get everything nicely aligned.

Comment: Hmmm thisProject seems to be returning correct values for every other variable. I tried to reset and build, but the error is still there.

Comment: Not an explanation but possibly a solution. Try defining explicit functions like function getAmountRaised() returns(uint amount) {return amountRaised;}, What you're seeing is consistent with function signatures that don't match even though it appears that they should. Possibly helps with getting on with life to stop relying on the freebie getters "public" provides. Other thought, it shouldn't matter, but thinking about quirks. uint256 = uint, so consider recasting all uint256 as straight uint.

Comment: Ok I've tried switching all uint256 to uint, and I tried defining explicit getter functions and they all seem to throw a jump error.

Comment: Bounty is a good idea. I would update the question with the most simplified, succinct and complete code someone can use to replicate the problem on their own and troubleshoot it.

Comment: There is a possibility we haven't explored because it's rare, but not *that* rare. The EVM uses 4-byte function signatures that are the first bytes of a hash of the function arguments. Due to it being only 4 bytes, risk of collision is high and this can cause bizarre outcomes. It's possible to calculate the sigs and prove/disprove but possibly faster to just rename some things to rule it out.

Comment: Ok so the only way I was able to get the variable to return a value is if I passed it as a parameter in the contructor function of Project(). Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Hey @RobHitchens I ran into this issue again later on and changing all of my variables to uint256 fixed the issue. Is it related to this? https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1306